# UIButton image goes grey on press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've gone through all the other questions concerning button color changes. Here's the situation, I have a button that when pressed causes a view to slide out. Before press the button's image is white, once pressed goes grey (this is acceptable), but when pressed again to return to original location, the image is still grey. I want it back to white and have tried using UIControlStateNormal, Disabled, etc with no success.

```
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

this has been changed to all UIControl types. currently it is set as:

```
[self.menu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.menu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

and still no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the white image is the one you have named @"someImage" and the grey one is the image called @"menu"? Can you show the code within the IBAction method for when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 10):

You can disable adjusting colours of button's subviews by setting property

```
myButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
```

Comment: This flag can be toggled also from Storyboard. Look for: "Highlighted Adjusts Image". Also "Disabled Adjusts Image".

Answer (score 8):

you have to  set the same image for both states of the button : -

```
self.button.setImage(ImageName, for: .normal)
self.button.setImage(ImageName, for: .highlighted)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shown simply declares which image the button will be depending on different states, however you will need to physically change the state of the button too so these images can be used for each state.

What I mean by this, is if you have the button show a different image for when the button is selected, you will need to change the button state to selected. To return the image to the original unselected image, you will need change the state back to unselected. For example, let's say within your viewDidLoad method you have the following code to declare the images for each of the button states:

```
//Set for normal state
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normalImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Set for selected state
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selctedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Now within your IBAction method you can toggle between the states

```
-(IBAction*)yourButtonIsPressed:(id)sender{

      if (!self.button.selected){ //This is checking button state

       //The code will run in here if the button is in a normal, unselected state. This is where you have you method here to slide in view etc

       //Now change the button to a selected state
       self.button.selected = YES;

      }else{
       //The code will now run in here if the button is already in a selected state and this is where you place your method to return the view etc

       //Now set the button back to an unselected state
       self.button.selected = NO;
      }
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It was something completely overlooked. I had the view opacity set. so:

```
self.layer.opacity = .60;
```

was the issue. Once I commented that line out, the button works like a charm. Thanks for the help Jim.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. It's always the simply oversights that seem to cause the bother. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you created the button programmatically make sure to set the type and change the image render mode to use original to maintain the image color.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "someImage").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOrigianl)
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
```